# Switch from UIView to ScrollView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

[image]

Originally, the number of menus was one, but it was changed to more than one.

So I want to change the UIView (Container View) so that I can scroll horizontally.

Shop Menu View Cell is TableView -> TableViewCell -> TableViewCell (This) on the screen.

I tried several ways to switch to the horizontal scroll view.

I have separated the Container View and made it into a Cell
I also tried adding Scroll View or UICollectionView.

But all the way was not what I wanted.
Perhaps the Shop Menu View Cell is due to having passed the TableView twice.

I could not solve it for four days.
Please give me a hint how to implement.

Comment: You mean you want to make the contents in your tableView cell scroll horizontally?

Comment: More precisely, I want to create multiple Container View and then scroll.

Comment: Did you tried using table view with container views(as tableView cell)?

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. If it is the correct implementation, I will try again.

Comment: From what I know, this is the appropriate implementation. But I may miss some points.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html  This guide may help.

Comment: Let me try again with your answer. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create editable forms of data display for static information, static `TableViewController` is best choice. As it automatically adjust your view when keyboard appear and other many feature, along with **scroll**. Plus you can directly *outlet* all the components to your controller class.

Your view will look something like:

[image]